# Eloquent Relationships, linking of models (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm kinda confused how the eloquent relationships works in Laravel 5.4.
I got a school model that has a "hasMany" relationship with my user model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

The user is not required to be linked to a school though, so I haven't put the belongsTo (school) function on my user model.

How should I link the user to a school, when I create the user and how can I pull all users in a specific school into a view, for example?

Comment: I would start here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships. The docs do a pretty good job walking through the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user can only belong to one school, the most straightforward approach would be to add a `school_id` column to the `users` table. Since it's not required, you can allow for it to be null. This will allow you to run `$school->users` to retrieve a list of users for a given school.

I would also recommend adding the `belongsTo` relationship to the User model, so you can do `$user->school` to retrieve a user's school when applicable. It's okay that it'll be null for some users.

Comment: I can't get "$school->users" to work. I tried $school = School::find(1); $school->users; and pass it to view with compact, but it doesn't work. I get this error: "FatalThrowableError in HasRelationships.php line 487:
Class 'App\Users' not found" - I added belongsTo (school) for my user model.

Comment: Is it defined as `App\Users` somewhere in your code? I suspect it should be `App\User` (singular).

Comment: Yeah, I mistyped "User" in my school relationship. I'm pretty tired, my bad! :S